# Equal-height scaling cells in an html table

Tags: html, html-table, cell, scaling

I'm having some trouble with HTML tables when I make this design:
The left-hand cell is a rowspan="2" cell, and the right two are using height="50%" attributes.
Below is the expected behavior:

```
    +-------------+-----------------+
    |             |                 |
    |             |   Equal-height  |
    |             |   cell #1       |
    |             |                 |
    | Scaling-    +-----------------+
    | height cell |                 |
    |             |   Equal-height  |
    |             |   cell #2       |
    |             |                 |
    +-------------+-----------------+
```

What actually happens:

```
    +-------------+-----------------+
    |             |   Equal-height  |
    |             |   cell #1       |
    |             +-----------------+
    |             |                 |
    | Scaling-    |                 |
    | height cell |   Equal-height  |
    |             |   cell #2       |
    |             |                 |
    |             |                 |
    +-------------+-----------------+
```

In short, the top of the right-hand two cells is reduced as small as possible, and the bottom one fills the rest of the space. There is an ugly workaround using embedded tables, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.
This can also be circumvented by assuming a fixed height for the left-hand cell, and forcing the size (in pixels) for the right-hand cells. This defeats the purpose of a scaling-height cell, though.

Comment: What browsers are you testing?

Comment: Try `table-layout: fixed`

Comment: you could use a div layout instead,,. here's a somewhat messy version - http://jsfiddle.net/Kx6w4/

Comment: Testing with browsers: Chrome, Safari (Mac OSX)

Comment: Current experiments with table-layout:fixed are not working, I've tried it in the table-header and table rows.<br>Divs don't scale, so that solution doesn't work.

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution to this one, any ideas?

Comment: Table-layout:fixed is only for width--although semi-useful is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the height:50% tag, the table needed to have a height. Again, the problem was to due with the element on the left being arbitrarily-sized. So, a fixed height (say 150px) might be a problem if the text on the left was less than 150 px. Thus, setting a 0px height table solved this problem.

```
<table height="0px" border="1px">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      Blah<br>
      Blah<br>
      Blah<br>
      Blah<br>
      Blah<br>
      Blah<br>
      Blah<br>
      Blah<br>
    </td>
    <td height="50%">
      Text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="50%">
      More text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Really late...how about using javascript as follows where height is a number you set?

```
function SetCellHeight(height) {
    document.getElementById('ReferenceCell').style.height = height + 'px';
    document.getElementById('Cell1').style.height = (0.5 * height) + 'px';     
    document.getElementById('Cell2').style.height = (0.5 * height) + 'px';
}

<body onload="SetCellHeight(height)">

<table border=1>
<tr>
<td id="ReferenceCell" rowspan="2">First Column</td>
<td id="Cell1">Cell #1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="Cell2">Cell #2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, the user can set height as follows:

```
function SetCellHeight() {
    var height = document.forms.tdHeightForm.heightinput.value.trim();
    document.getElementById('ReferenceCell').style.height = height + 'px';
    document.getElementById('Cell1').style.height = (0.5 * height) + 'px';     
    document.getElementById('Cell2').style.height = (0.5 * height) + 'px';
}

<form id="tdHeightForm"><input type="text" name="heightinput"><button type="button" 
onclick="SetCellHeight()">Change Height</button></form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this was on a wiki, so javascript wasn't allowed. I did in fact solve this problem by adding a height:0px to the parent cell-this was clearly not going to effect the height of the cell, but did allow the percentage-based scaling to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" style="height:300px;width:100px;text-align:center">First Column</td>
<td style="height: 150px;width:100px;text-align:center">Cell #1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height:150px;width:100px;text-align:center">Cell #2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want to use fixed-height. Thus, this is not a solution.