# Scaling table cell height

Tags: html, css, html-table, cell, scaling

Firstly, this is a duplicate question: [Equal-height scaling cells in an html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056338/equal-height-scaling-cells-in-an-html-table)

The user that asked the question above didn't get a solution for the same issue I'm having.

Within the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pAz6G/) you will notice a cell with a **red background**. This cell is the **highest** and I need all other cells to pick up the **highest** cell height and span to the corresponding cell height.

**The solution cannot contain fixed heights as this must be dynamic**

Here is a mock up of what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/pAz6G/

Here is **HTML**:

```
<table class="left" cellspacing="0" borderspacing="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>            
            <h2>Very Servere</h2>
            <p>50m from high water on East Coast, 100m from high water on West Coast. Characterised by:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Heavy salt deposits</li>
                <li>The almost constant smell of saly spray in the air.</li>
                <li>Close to breaking stuff (typically starts 50-100 metres) such as is found on exposed coasts.</li>
            </ul>
            <p>This environment may be extended inland by revailing winds and local coniditions</p>         
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" borderspacing="0" class="right">
    <tr>
        <td class="section">
            <span class="section-heading">Applications</span>
            <table class="inner">
                <tr>
                    <td>Roofing</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Roofing</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Roofing</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td class="section">
            <span class="section-heading">Applications</span>
            <table class="inner">
                <tr>
                    <td>Roofing</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Roofing</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Roofing</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td class="section">
            <span class="section-heading">Applications</span>
            <table class="inner">
                <tr>
                    <td>Roofing</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="red">Rain washing plus manual washing every 3 months</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Roofing</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is **CSS**:

```
/* Column Styling */

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
}

    .left td {
        padding: 10px;
    }

.right {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}
/*********************************************/

/* General Styling */

.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}

td {
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: top;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

/*********************************************/

/* Section Styling */

.section {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.section-heading {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

/*********************************************/

/* Nested Tables */

.inner {
    width: 100%;
}

.inner td {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

/*********************************************/
```

Comment: I've reviewed this further with my colleagues and have come up with a solution. I will post a working solution once it's completed. The thinking we have is the cells that need the same height - they need to be within the same table context - currently they are individual so cannot pick up each others cell height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using multiple tables, try using one table.

Keeping it simple  :)